# Alinhar div no centro e à esquerda

Tags: html, div, css

Olá, estou com uma dúvida quanto ao alinhamento de div. Eu tenho uma situação onde tenho várias divs dentro de uma outra. Eu quero que as divs internas fiquem alinhadas ao centro, mas que quando haja quebra de linha, a div que foi para a segunda linha vá para a posição na esquerda, exatamente abaixo da primeira div na primeira linha.

Só que para fazer isso também não posso utilizar width e height pré-definidos, pois quero que a div de fora se auto ajuste.

Segue um exemplo da situação que tenho atualmente:

```css
.fora {
  background-color: black;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.quadrado {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="fora">
  <div class="quadrado"></div>
  <div class="quadrado"></div>
  <div class="quadrado"></div>
  <div class="quadrado"></div>
  <div class="quadrado"></div>
  <div class="quadrado"></div>
</div>
```

O espaço na borda direita está maior do que na borda esquerda, o que eu gostaria é que o espaçamento entre as bordas permanecesse igual.

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Talvez por esse link fique mais fácil de visualizar a situação: https://jsfiddle.net/jarlan/34fns1uc/21/

Comment: Cara se entendi bem, acho que a matemática não vai deixar. Pois, se vc tem uma div pai com largura **auto**, ou seja vai se ajustar ao tamanho da janela e colocou as divs filhas com largura de **90px**, vai ter hora que janela não vai caber mais uma div filha na mesma linha, logo, irá jogar a div filha para baixo, ficando aquele espaço na direita.

Comment: Mas não tem problema de quebrar a linha, o que eu queria é só que quando quebrasse a linha, não ficasse desproporcional o tamanho das bordas.

E se eu alinhar os elementos internos vai ficar assim:
div1 div2 div3 <aqui quebra a linha>
       div4 (embaixo da div2)

o que eu queria é que ficasse assim:
div1 div2 div3 <aqui quebra a linha>
div4 (embaixo da div1)

só que essa segunda opção com mesma distância nas bordas esquerdas e direita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma opção para isso, mas não é com `flexbox` é com `grid`.

Aqui tem um exemplo prático e mais explicações. https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example28/

Aqui segue um exemplo baseado no que vc ficou com dúvida. Mas o principal é entender como funciona essa linha no css `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(90px, 1fr));` Aqui eu defini que cada célula do grid vai ter no mínimo 90px de largura e um máximo de 1fr, porém o quadrado de dentro sempre fica dom 90x90px. Repare que as margens laterais sempre são iguais.

**OBS:** O `container` não precisa ter uma lagura, só que sem uma largura os itens vão ficar espalhados pela tela, ou vc coloca mais itens ou determina uma largura para evitar esse espaçamento do itens. Teste o exemplo em diferentes resoluções para entender.

```css
.fora {
    padding: 30px 60px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(90px, 1fr));
    background-color: black;
    color: #444;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.quadrado {
    background-color: gray;
    color: #fff;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="fora">
        <div class="quadrado">A</div>
        <div class="quadrado">B</div>
        <div class="quadrado">C</div>
        <div class="quadrado">D</div>
        <div class="quadrado">E</div>
        <div class="quadrado">F</div>
        <div class="quadrado">G</div>
        <div class="quadrado">H</div>
        <div class="quadrado">I</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Viu Hugo só  que ele diz que não pode setar width na div pai, tem que ser auto.

Comment: @LeAndrade cara fiz um edite na pergunta e coloquei umas observações. Agora não tem largura fixa, mas tb os itens ficam mais espalhados na tela.... Nesse casso está difícil conseguir o melhor dos dois mundos... Mas teste a responsividade ai pra vc ver o resultado, até que ficou legal!

Comment: Exato Hugo, como falei pra ele não tinha como não criar espaços na direita na maneira que ele queria.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, esse é exatamente o efeito que eu buscava. Eu precisava que os itens ficassem alinhados em qualquer resolução, mas que quando houvesse a quebra de linha não ficasse aquela espaço desigual em um dos cantos. Valeu.

Comment: @Jarlan nesse caso acho que só com o grid mesmo, pq vc pode ajustar os subitens em relação a célula do container e ainda assim fica responsivo direitinho. Logico que tem uns pros e uns contras, mas nessa situação foi a melhor opção que encontrei, boa sorte ai.